Alternative naming conventions in clang-tidy
Is there any possibility to use alternatives in readability-identifier-naming rules in clang-tidy? Specifically, I want to use
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantPrefix, value: sc_ }

and
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantPrefix, value: k }

at the same time in .clang-tidy; it may be useful for an old and a new code in the same project. Such a syntax сould be
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantCase, value: CamelCase | camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantPrefix, value: sc_ | k }

or even (much more clearly for me)
ClassConstant:
  - case: camelBack, prefix: sc_
  - case: CamelCase, prefix: k

or something else.
